# Why can't I resolve ~ with shell=True with subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I try to run this command:

```
subprocess.call('''psql --username=openerp --dbname=sf_template_20150605121222 --no-password --command="select table_schema, table_name, count_rows(table_schema, table_name) from information_schema.tables where table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') and table_type='BASE TABLE' order by 1, 2 desc" > ~/sf_template.old.txt''', shell=True)
```

And get an error like this in the shell:

```
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create ~/sf_template.old.txt: Directory nonexistent
```

Wham am I doing wrong? Why can't I write the file resolving ~ to my current user home? The user is a regular user (i.e. my current logged in user), which has its home directory.

Comment: I think you need `os.path.expanduser("~/sf_template.old.txt")`

Comment: Works for me on Mac; is `HOME` set?

Comment: @JoranBeasley, yes, you'll need that if the shell doesn't do the expansion, but the reason this is a valid and interesting question is that if it's not in a quoted shell context, the shell *should* do that expansion.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: that's normally taken care of by the shell.

Comment: ...now, relying on a shell here is bad practice for numerous reasons, but that's somewhat beside the point. :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, ...actually, on OS X, I can't reproduce even when explicitly clearing `HOME`: `python -c 'import os, subprocess; os.unsetenv("HOME"); subprocess.call("""echo ~""", shell=True)'`. Curious.

Comment: if OP is on windows that would explain alot ... and my original comment would still apply... maybe need is the wrong word... but should use the expanduser function ... or expandvars depending on which is appropriate

Comment: @JoranBeasley ty :D. I am in Ubuntu. Solved it.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: `/bin/sh` in the output hints that it is not Windows. Actually, It is an interesting question: under what conditions `/bin/sh` won't expand `~`.

Comment: To answer the above question: [*"If the login name is null (that is, the tilde-prefix contains only the tilde), the tilde-prefix is replaced by the value of the variable HOME. If HOME is unset, the results are unspecified."*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01) -- on my Ubuntu machine: `~` is expanded even if HOME, LOGNAME are unset (in zsh). `sh` doesn't expand `~` if HOME is not set.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that `~` is not expanded in your case. It suggests that you've passed a wrong environment:

```
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call('echo >~/nonexistent/dir', shell=True)
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/me/nonexistent/dir: Directory nonexistent
2
>>> call('echo >~/nonexistent/dir', shell=True, env={})
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create ~/nonexistent/dir: Directory nonexistent
2
>>> call('echo >~/nonexistent/dir', shell=True, env=dict(HOME='abc'))
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create abc/nonexistent/dir: Directory nonexistent
2
```

Notice: the tilde is expanded in the first and the last case.

You should probably use `env=dict(os.environ, YOUR_VAR='1')` instead of `env=dict(YOUR_VAR='1')`.

[POSIX defines Tilde expansion as](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01):

> If the login name is null (that is, the tilde-prefix contains only the
>   tilde), the tilde-prefix is replaced by the value of the variable
>   HOME. If HOME is unset, the results are unspecified.